# Facebook Api v2.2 - get album's photos shares count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following Graph Api query in order to receive the likes and comments counts on all the photos in an Album inside my page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/album_id?fields=photos.limit(250){likes.limit(1),comments.limit(1),id,source},likes.limit(1)&access_token=my_access_token
```

I want to to also receive each one of these pictures shares count, but the share count is not connected to the photo end point, Its connected to the page_story_id.

So, in order to receive all the shares count i'm going to need to query each of those individually, which doesn't make sense when you have an album with 200 pictures (not to mention an album with 500 pictures).

FQL is deprecated after v2.1 so I can't use the FQL to get this (which will defiantly ease everything for me).

Isn't there an easier way to do so?

**Update**
Thanks to @CBroe comments, this is my batch:

```
[
 {
   "method":"GET",
  "name":"get-photos",
  "relative_url":"951337131548012?fields=photos.limit(250){likes.limit(1),comments.limit(1),id,source,page_story_id},likes.limit(1)"
  },
 {
  "method":"GET",
  "relative_url":"/?ids={result=get-photos:$.photos.data.*.page_story_id}"
 }
]
```

Now it does return all the photos post objects, but how can I query them all the specific field? like add `?fields=shares`

Comment: You can request data for more than one id at a time. And batch requests also exist.

Comment: @CBroe can you please provide some more information ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#multirequests, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Comment: So I tried the combination of both. I've added an update to my question

Answer (score 2):

ok after struggling with this for few hours, and thank to @CBroe help I found the right batch request for my needs and it involves both batch and Graph API multiple requests.

```
[
 {
   "method":"GET",
  "name":"get-photos",
  "relative_url":"951337131548012?fields=photos.limit(250){likes.limit(1),comments.limit(1),id,source,page_story_id},likes.limit(1)"
  },
 {
  "method":"GET",
  "relative_url":"/?ids={result=get-photos:$.photos.data.*.page_story_id}&fields=shares"
 }
]
```

by adding `&fields=shares` i'm filtering the fields of inner results of the multi request.

Hope it helps someone :)