# Facebook Batch returns: Some of the aliases you requested do not exist

Tags: facebook, facebook-batch-request

I'm building this batch in order to get all the share counts for all the pictures in an album (and like and comments on each photo):

My Batch:

```
[
 {
   "method":"GET",
   "name":"get-photos",
   "relative_url":"951337131548012?fields=photos.limit(250){likes.limit(1),comments.limit(1),id,source,page_story_id},likes.limit(1)"
 },
 {
   "method":"GET",
   "relative_url":"{result=get-photos:$.photos.data.*.page_story_id}?fields=shares"
 }
]
```

It always returns `Some of the aliases you requested do not exist` with the page_story_id number, but when i'm querying the graph api for that story id i get the data..

any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

As I answered my question asked here: [Facebook Api v2.2 - get album's photos shares count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558311/facebook-api-v2-2-get-albums-photos-shares-count)

The right batch request should be:

```
[
 {
   "method":"GET",
  "name":"get-photos",
  "relative_url":"951337131548012?fields=photos.limit(250){likes.limit(1),comments.limit(1),id,source,page_story_id},likes.limit(1)"
  },
 {
  "method":"GET",
  "relative_url":"/?ids={result=get-photos:$.photos.data.*.page_story_id}&fields=shares"
 }
]
```